# Questions about factor groups of $\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I'm not familiar with modules so much and my teacher didn't go over it very well. So I was wondering if someone could help on some of these...at least a starting point.

List the elements of $A \in \mathbb Z/14\mathbb Z$ for which there is some $B \in \mathbb Z/14\mathbb Z$ such that $AB = [1]$. I believe there will be some kind of pattern with this but I'm not positive how to go about it.

Also find the subgroup of $\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z$ generated by $[2]$.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Well, can you do the very first thing, that is, can you list all the elements of $Z/14Z$?

Comment: @YACP Your title edit seems strange, as the first question is concerned with $\mathbb{Z}/14\mathbb{Z}$ as a ring, not as a group.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$ab=[1]=1\pmod{14}\iff \exists\,k\in\Bbb Z\;\;s.t.\;\;ab=1+14k\iff ab-14k=1\iff$$

$$\text{g.c.d.}(a,14)=1\iff a=1,3,5,9,11,13\pmod{14}$$

So only the integers that are coprime with $\,14\,$ will have what we call a multiplicative inverse in $\,\Bbb Z/14\Bbb Z\;$.

For the second question:

$$\langle 2\rangle=\{\;2,4,6,8,10,\ldots\;\}$$

**But** , of course, don't forget that, for example, $\,8=0\pmod 8\;,\;10=2\pmod 8\;\ldots$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

The notion of module isn't needed here and just we use that $(\mathbb Z/14 \mathbb Z,+,\times)$ is a ring.

You look for the elements $A\in \mathbb Z/14\mathbb Z$ such that $AB=[1]$ which means that $A$ is invertible in $\mathbb Z/14\mathbb Z$ so $A=[k]$ such that $\gcd(k,14)=1$ so 
$$A\in\{[1],[3],[5],[9],[11],[13]\}$$

For the second question
$$\langle [2]\rangle=\{[0],[2],[4],[6],[8]\}$$

Comment: Going by what the OP wrote, surely the point of this question is to  use modules, no?

Comment: @user1729 I don't see any broad commutative algebra based thinking here, either in understanding or in solving the question. It seems this whole business could be conducting without making any reference to modules, only abelian groups. Are you thinking of "modulus" from "modular arithmetic"?

Comment: $\mathbb Z/14\mathbb Z$ can be seen as a module but really I don't think this is necessary.

Comment: @anon The title is "Abstract Math Module Question" and the first sentence is "I'm not familiar with modules so much and my teacher didn't go over it very well." So what I mean is that the OP seems to want help with modules and this is the question he wants help with them on, rather than just "What is the answer to this question? I think it might have something to do with modules..."

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Perhaps you could explain why you cannot see $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ as a module in your answer then?

Comment: @user1729 No I didn't say that $\mathbb Z/14\mathbb Z$ isn't a module but I said that the module structure isn't needed.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Oh, sorry, missread what your wrote and didn't think to see if it made sense! I know the module structure isn't needed, but my point is that the OP is struggling with modules and, well, what I said in my above comment to anon.

Comment: @user1729 What's the difference if we see $\mathbb Z/14\mathbb Z$ as a ring or as a module? for the former the multiplication of the elements of $\mathbb Z/14\mathbb Z$ is an internal operation and in the last the multiplication is an external operation and just I said to the OP that using the module concept here does not have a particularity.

Comment: @user1729 Yes, OP is having problem with modules in general and also wants help with this problem. I don't think anyone indicates or believes otherwise. You seem to be suggesting though there are aspects of this problem that are unique to module theory not contained in basic ring theory thinking that need to be explained to the OP; feel free to point these out yourself if you think there are any. Yet you also say you know module structure isn't needed. Ultimately I am at a loss trying to figure out what you want to see come about in the wake of this thread of confusion now precipitated...

Comment: @anon I dunno. I think I am confused now! My point was "So what if we don't need to use modules, the OP *wants to use them!*" (by my interpretation of what the OP said).

Comment: @anon I do not find very useful to talk to OP on the module while most elementary notions of groups and rings are not known to him.

Comment: I don't think OP has expressed *desire* to use them; my impression was that OP only provided context in case it was useful for potential answerers in how they craft their answers; whether or not the information actually turns out useful being for answerers to decide. There is also a chance OP is confusing modules with modular arithmetic (which I take as further evidence this belongs more *natively* as an exercise to elementary number theory or basic ring theory than module theory in commutative algebra).